# How to play flv video file in Android Chrome browser

Tags: android, html

I want to play flv and mp4 videos on my android chrome browser. Here is my html code for displaying video.But I am unable to play video on android  mobile chrome browser. Can any one help to achieve this

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: <html>
 <body>
  <video id="example_video_1" controls preload="auto" width="440" height="264"
   poster="video.imageUrl">
            <source src="video_url.flv" type="video/flv">
     <source src= "video_url.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video> 
 
 </body>
</html>